# Javascript global variable access

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me understand why the value of x is 'undefined'?

```
var x = 100;

function test() {

    if(false) {

        var x = 199;
    }

    alert(x);
}

test();
```

Comment: Because variables are local to the current function scope

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+hoisting

Comment: @litelite The `x` outside of the function gets shadowed by the `x` declared inside the function

Comment: Even it is declared and assigned inside the `if(false)` statement Javascript run something called **hoisting**, that pop ups all the variables declared inside a closure in to the beginning of that closure.

So the variable is assigned inside the `if` but it is really declared previously. As the code asks for the x value it prints Undefined. 

The x global variable is not taked in account because there is another with the same name declared inside the closure of the funcion test. 

Check https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Answer (score 0):

When you define a new variable inside your if it is visible only inside it.

Considering that you declare again the variable x by writing var before, it become a variable visible only inside the if.

By removing that var, it will be changed if the if verifies and the alert will always work.

```js
var x = 100;

function test() {

    if(false) {

        x = 199;
    }

    //alert(x);
    console.log(x);
}

test();
```

Comment: Why not declaring the variable inside the `test()` function?

Comment: "a variable visible only inside the `if`" – no, not really. That doesn't explain the behaviour.

Comment: @Jer idk it depends from what he needs, i just explained which was the problem ^^

Comment: @deceze yes really, if you instantiate  a new variable inside an if as he did, it will be visible only inside it ^^

Comment: So why is the alert giving `undefined` instead of `100` or alternatively `ReferenceError`?!

Comment: cause he can't see the value cause it has been declared inside the if as i said

Comment: Then why isn't the value `100`?

Comment: cause he declared again the variable as a new variable, not visible cause of the scope

Comment: Aha! That's rather missing from your answer. Or at the very least unclear.

Comment: My answer looks clear to me, maybe it's cause english isn't my most used language ^^

Comment: @MarcoSalerno You need to learn the difference between declaring a variable and assigning a value to a variable. It's always two different processes that happens separately, even if JS syntax makes it look like one single process, which is why confusions like this happen.

Comment: I just know the difference